# Shared LED strip data line with multiple power supplies

Tags: power-supply, power, led-strip

I am wanting to drive a long run of addressable LED strips using multiple power supplies to accommodate power requirements.  At no point am I going to connect the positive terminal of each power supply together as I know this will cause problems.  I am however wanting to share a data line between power supply runs (see diagram).

I have wired up this diagram and it appears to be partially working but the second LED strip will glitch out quite frequently (random colours, not in sync with strip 1). This seems to indicate the data signal into the second strip is not very clean.

Is there a way to pass current between power supply 1 and power supply 2 in the way of the data signal that will not be too noisy?

[image]

Comment: Does strip 3 work ok?

Comment: I haven't wired up strip 3 yet, was trying to get strip 2 working properly first.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was significant enough power drop by the end of the first LED strip that it did not have enough power to reliably pass the data signal on to the second strip.  Adding in a power injection at the end of the first resolved the problem.